# Fill a list object with multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I currently have this list

```
    public static List<Tablea> AllTablesList()
     {
          using (var context = new EFContext())
         {
            return context.Tableas
                 .Include(p => p.Tablebs)
                 .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Which I want to expand with with the ICollection as stated in Tableb, which uses data from table C. The list however inherits from  Tablea, all the references I've tried to tablec fail because of this.

```
public class Tablea : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int TableaID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tableb> Tablebs { get; set; }
}

public class Tableb : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int TablebID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TableaID { get; set; }
    public Tablea Tablea { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tablec> Tablecs { get; set; }
```

What would be the best way to include the collection in tableb?

Comment: What's the purpose of `.Select(p => p)`? What's wrong with the return value if you remove it?

Comment: @mm8 Seemed to be a copy/paste mistake of mine, thanks for noting it. Removed it and edited the post accordingly

Comment: It's still unclear what the question is. What exactly "fails" and how?

Comment: All `Tablea` entities are in `context.Tableas`, aren't they? So which entities are you missing?

Comment: @mm8 TableC is its own entity. The list that I want to create needs data from A which has child entities in B, and B which has child entities in C. The list is based on A and can use data from B. I cant however seem to expand the list to include C as well, because the base of the list in still in A. I'm wondering what would be the best way to achieve this

Comment: What you need to fill in objects from Tablea and Tableb, is a common base class or common interface these two implement. It would contain common fields like `Name`. Then you can declare a list as `List<CommonBaseType>` or `List<CommonInterface>`.

Comment: `Include(p => p.Tablebs.Select(x => x.Tablecs))` ? Is this what you mean/want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is that you want is to eager load TableCs along with TableBs when loading TableAs. It's not clear though when you state things like "the list however inherits from Tablea"

```
return context.Tableas
    .Include(p => p.Tablebs)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Tablecs)
    .ToList();
```

If instead you want to present a table of all TableCs for each TableA (through the TableB references, I.e. you want to render TableCs, not TableAs but load them through the TableA:

```
return context.Tableas
    .SelectMany(a => a.Tablebs.SelectMany(b => b.Tablecs))
    .ToList();
```

Though generally if filtering on TableA, it makes more sense to navigate back from C, and include each's B and A if you need details from those:

```
return context.Tablecs
    .Include(c => c.Tableb)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.TableA)
    .ToList();
```

This would return an `IEnumerable<TableC>` with eager loading each B and A reference rather than an `IEnumerable<TableA>` with the eager loaded Bs and Cs.

Ultimately though when it comes to rendering a hierarchy of relational data into a "flat" data table for a view I would strongly recommend defining a view model and using `Select` to project the relational data to express just the columns from the various entities to fill your flattened view Model. This has the advantage of sending considerably less data across the wire to the client. This would depend entirely on what data from each related table the view needs to present. (I.e. a row per "A" with a summary of B and or C, or a row per "C" with details from the related B and A...)

Otherwise you need to provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem if there is a particular class inheritance / relationship desired that is conflicting with EF to get the data you want.